# reading a NSDictionary from plist issue with BOOL value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdictionary

So I have the following method:

```
- (void)readPlist
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"States" ofType:@"plist"];    
    self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    BOOL value = (BOOL)[self.data valueForKey:@"Arizona"];
    NSLog(@"VALUE IS %d", value);

}
```

It reads the plist fine, it can detect that it has 7 keys, however when I try to print the value out it gives me 32 if it's a no and 24 if it's a yes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

valueForKey returns an id. Do this:

```
NSNumber * n = [self.data valueForKey:@"Arizona"];
BOOL value = [n boolValue];
```

Comment: You should not use `valueForKey:`. Use `objectForKey:`, or these days, use modern syntax `NSNumber * n = self.data[@"Arizona"];`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)readPlist
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"States" ofType:@"plist"];    
self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

BOOL value = [[self.data valueForKey:@"Arizona"] intValue];
NSLog(@"VALUE IS %i", value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would chip in on this. First thing is, how to property define a BOOL value in your plist?

[Apple's DTD for plist](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd) gives a decent clue:

```
<!ENTITY % plistObject "(array | data | date | dict | real | integer | string | true | false )" >
```

and later:

```
<!-- Numerical primitives -->
<!ELEMENT true EMPTY>  <!-- Boolean constant true -->
<!ELEMENT false EMPTY> <!-- Boolean constant false -->
```

All great, but how does that look in the plist?

Well, for a true value, it would be:

```
    <dict>
        <key>employeeId</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Joe Smith</string>
        <key>worksRemotely</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

and of course for false:

```
    <dict>
        <key>employeeId</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Joe Smith</string>
        <key>worksRemotely</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
```

To create an object from the plist, as a keen user of [Objectify](http://tigerbears.com/objectify/), I take inspiration from their factory classes. My `Employee` class would have these methods:

```
+ (Employee *)instanceFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {

    Employee *instance = [[Employee alloc] init];

    [instance setAttributesFromDictionary:aDictionary];
    return instance;
}
```

that in turn calls:

```
- (void)setAttributesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {

    if (![aDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return;
    }

    [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:aDictionary];

}
```

`setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:aDictionary` is a member of the [NSKeyValueCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). That's available with every `NSObject` which means as as a subclass of `NSObject`, our `Employee` class gets that for free.

As long as my Employee class' properties match with the key values specified in the plist, namely `employeeId`, `name`, and `worksRemotely`, then I won't need to do anything else. That method will translate the `worksRemotely` boolean specified in the plist to the correct value in my class instance:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isWorkingRemotely) BOOL worksRemotely;
```

All that's left is to iterate through the plist contents, creating the instances of my desired class, bool included:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"employees" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *employeeDictionaries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
for (NSDictionary *employeeDict in employeeDictionaries) {
     Employee *employee = [Employee instanceFromDictionary:employeeDict];
     [employees addObject:employee];
}
```

No doubt I've gone a bit over the top in answering the specific question. However hopefully this can be of use to someone else who stumbled across this question whilst trying to do what I was trying, i.e. create a class with a boolean value in a plist.